# PHP question closed because apparently it was a duplicate, but I believe it's not

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I posted a question regarding a php/html error I was facing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540064/unable-to-get-html5s-option-element-to-display-value-in-php)  and someone deemed it to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) link . 
While I understand the error message was the same, my question is in no shape or form answered by the suggested link. What can I do about this?

Comment: As I know, explain why your question is different by editing the question, then the question will throw to the review queue automatically, if active reviewers agree, the question will be reopened. During review, you can only wait...

Answer (score 8):

Simple really. It is a duplicate.

The error you were getting is because the index of `$_POST` is not defined. It's not defined because it was never set. Therefore it is a duplicate of that linked question.

In future I would attempt some simple debugging yourself. `print_r($_POST);` is a good place to start in this case.

Comment: "Simple really. It is a duplicate" - Admin is god :)